# facebook graph app in php: how to attend group event as soon as it's published?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

is such a facebook app written in php possible at all with the current graph api?

i am a member of a closed group on fb. there are three sources for me to get to know about the new events of this group - my notifications, group events, the events of the author of the event (my fb friend). the app must constantly monitor one of these sources and must attend the new event with as little lag as possible as soon as it is published.

i am still missing some pieces of the picture (permissions maybe) after googling and the manual. would appreciate any advice, links.

Comment: I would be interested to know if this is possible also. Everything I've researched says it is not.  In my case, I wanted users to be able to create events (through the API) and have friends respond with Yes/No/Maybe that they are attending those events (through the API or Facebook).  I'm pretty sure that is not possible through the API.

Comment: the thing is the number of attendees is limited and the limit is reached in less than a minute. so, it seems i need one request with the correct permissions to list the events of this group for today. i request this every 3 seconds for a couple of hours if this is allowed. as soon as it returns an id of the event i fire another request sending the "attend" of the event with this id. can anyone give (point to) the examples of such requests?

Answer (score 0):

This would be equivalent to auto-posting, which isn't allowed on Facebook Platform.